# SQL Azure resource limit and how EXEC affects it

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure where I read data from 5 tables. The data returned from table number 4 is actually invoked via EXECuting another stored procedure.

Stored procedure:

```
    SELECT from tbl_1
    SELECT from tbl_2
    SELECT from tbl_3
    EXEC sproc2 -- returns rows from tbl_4
    SELECT from tbl_5
```

Interestingly, while doing `dataReader.NextResult` in C# for rows from table 5 I realise that there is no result. This does not happen frequently, but I did notice this happening a few times.

The error that I notice from SqlAzure is

> that database resource limit is reached.

Shouldn't the entire stored procedure run in a single thread and should be immune to limit usage issues once it starts executing? Or is it because of round robin scheduling where SQL Server could not restart my stored procedure execution due to unavailable resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after running a bunch of queries in the query store and trying to figure out what has been happening with my database, this is what I figured out

1. There were some long running queries that we run once in a while, queries that do cleanup and queries that collect logs. Unfortunately, they decided to run at the same time. These queries were granted large memory by SQL.
2. Random queries started timing out and I noticed that they were blocked with a `resource_semaphore_query_compile` wait type. This means that SQL didn't have a cached plan for this query and it didn't even have enough memory to compile the query again.
3. The total memory assigned to MEMORY_SQLQERESERVATIONS was high while the one to the plan cache was low, this is what I compared with general memory usage on the sql server.

To summarise, due to queries in 1, 2 happened and it resulted in 3.

In terms of the question that I had asked, sproc2 was a big query and was somehow always getting evicted from the plan cache.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the entire stored procedure run in a single thread

When you submit a query to SQL Server, it may choose to run the query in parallel based on many conditions. One of them is `cost Threshold for Parallelism`. So for your first question the answer is it depends

FYI.. many times a query will benefit from running in parallel, so parallelism is not always bad.

Coming to your scenario and ask..

> Shouldn't the entire stored procedure run in a single thread and should be immune to limit usage issues once it starts executing?

SQL Server can estimate memory required for the query and can halt its execution (won't even start), until it has enough memory to start ..

But in Azure DTU is a combination of memory, IO, CPU and any of them can reach their quota and there is no way to restrain a query to use limited IO, CPU

So a query can stop in **between** if DTU is severely constrained, after their wait time is over.

To troubleshoot this, Azure offers [performance insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-query-performance) to know more on DTU usage by query, so that you can fine tune them.

With performance insight, you can get

1. deeper insight into your databases resource (DTU) consumption.
2. The top queries by CPU/Duration/Execution count, which can potentially be tuned for improved performance.
3. The ability to drill down into the details of a query, view its text and history of resource utilization.